# Unable to login into Spark using static IP after port forwarding

Tags: linux, xmpp

I installed `openfire` in `CentOS 6.4 server` (IP address: `192.168.1.118`) and I was able to login into `spark` using the server as `192.168.1.118`.

We want to use `spark` from outside, so I did port forwarding in my `dlink` router with `192.168.1.118` and `9090` (default port of `openfire`). Even allowed it as public.

We have a public static IP, for example `xxx.x.xx.xx` and if I give this public IP as server in Spark I am unable to login. But if type `xxx.x.xx.xx:9090` in browser I can get the openfire admin page.

Why am I unable to connect to Spark client even after port forwarding?
It is not working in Windows even.